# Javascript Web Component: this.shadowRoot.querySelector() always returns null

Tags: javascript, web-component

I am making a web component with vanilla JavaScript as follows:

```html
<template id="TEMPLATE_UPLOADER">
<div>Try Query Me</div>
</template>

<script>
customElements.define('my-uploader', class extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        const template = document.getElementById("TEMPLATE_UPLOADER");
        const content = template.content;
        let superThis = super()  // Create and binds the this keyword
        let shadowRoot = superThis.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
        shadowRoot.appendChild(template.cloneNode(content, true));
    }

    /** Custom Component Reactions **/
    connectedCallback() {
        setTimeout(this.init.bind(this), 1000)
    }
   
    init() {
        const el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('div');
        console.log('I hope el is not null:', el)
    }
});
</script>
<my-uploader></my-uploader>
```

Now within `init()` I wish to query some of elements within the template for this component. However `this.shadowRoot.querySelector` always returns `null`. I red that the elements are not yet created at `connectedCallback` time, so I set a timeout to call `init()` after 1 second to ensure it was finished being created, but got the same result. This is what `this.shadowRoot` looks like in Chrome (side note `this` is `<my-uploader></my-uploader>`):

[image]

As you can see there are `divs` inside, however `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('div')` returns null. How to query items within the web component?

Comment: Try to create a working SO Snippet with that [ < > ] button in the SO editor. Makes it easier to for us to copy/paste/change.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thanks for explaining to use the [< >], I made a snippet, I always wondered how people embedded these live demos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template.cloneNode(content, true)`

Should be: `template.cloneNode(true)`

Your `content` is a DOM reference interpreted FALSE, thus you created a SHALLOW copy, without the `<div>`

I condensed your code a bit

```html
<template id="TEMPLATE_UPLOADER">
  <div>Try Query Me</div>
</template>

<script>
customElements.define('my-uploader', class extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        const template = document.getElementById("TEMPLATE_UPLOADER").content;
        super()
           .attachShadow({mode: "open"})
           .append(template.cloneNode(true));
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        setTimeout( () => this.init() ); // don't learn JRs that oldskool bind stuff
    }
   
    init() {
        const el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('div');
        console.log('I hope el is not null:', el)
    }
});
</script>
<my-uploader></my-uploader>
```

Comment: Thanks so much again for the help! Yes I prefer the code a little longer so its easier for me to understand. Oh I see when I refactored my code I introduced this error. But I am glad I refactored it, I think your way of doing it in the constructor is more resilent, like you said if the element moves etc, then connectedCallback fires again. Big thank you again!